# django modelchoicefield with distinct column values

Tags: python, django

What I'd like to do is populate a `select` element with distinct values from one column in the model table.

my forms.py:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    only_unique_values = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required = False,
        queryset = ReadOnlyTable.objects.values('pie').distinct(),
        widget = forms.Select
    )
```

Using the `values` function returns a `ValuesQuerySet` instead of a `QuerySet`, which is a problem for my `select` element because all the options are populated with the dictionary syntax as the values instead of just the column data as `string`s.

**It ends up looking like this**:

```
<select id="id_example" name="example_form">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="{'pie': u'apple     '}">{'pie': u'apple     '}</option>
<option value="{'pie': u'pecan     '}">{'pie': u'pecan     '}</option>
<option value="{'pie': u'dutch     '}">{'pie': u'dutch     '}</option>
<option value="{'pie': u'pumpkin     '}">{'pie': u'pumpkin     '}</option>
</select>
```

**How I would want it to look is like so**:

```
<select id="id_example" name="example_form">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="pecan">pecan</option>
<option value="dutch">dutch</option>
<option value="pumpkin">pumpkin</option>
</select>
```

**How can I return `string` values from a `distinct()` call on my model?**

Comment: Are you using postgresql? If so you could always do ...objects.all().distinct('pie')

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 No, SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A model choice field is for selecting instances from your model. If you are selecting values from the model instances, then a model choice field isn't suitable any more.

You can use a choice field instead, and set the choices in the form's `__init__` method.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    only_unique_values = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
        choices=[],
        widget=forms.Select,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['only_unique_values'].choices = ReadOnlyTable.objects.values_list('pie', 'pie').distinct()
```

Doing `values_list('pie', 'pie')` give you the list of two-tuples required by the choice field.

In Django 1.8+, you don't need to override `__init__` any more. Instead, you can define a callable that returns the list of choices, and pass the callable to your choice field.

```
def unique_values():
    return ReadOnlyTable.objects.values_list('pie', 'pie').distinct()

class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    only_unique_values = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
        choices=unique_values,
        widget=forms.Select,
    )
```

To include a blank option in your choice field, just add an item to the list of choices:

```
def unique_values():
    return [("", "---------")] + list(ReadOnlyTable.objects.values_list('pie', 'pie').distinct())
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `ChoiceField` here?

Comment: Yes, it should be a choice field. Fixed now.

Comment: And does this kill the default value option?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Your question might be clearer if you showed your model and view.

Comment: The form widget has the default option of `---------` when the pages loads. Providing the choices in `__init__` doesn't give me that result. Not a horrible by-product, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: If you want to add an empty choice, you can do `choices = [("", "---------")] + list(ReadOnlyTable.objects.values_list('pie', 'pie').distinct())`.

Comment: Hmmm... says `can only concatenate list (not "ValuesListQuerySet") to list`

Comment: You've missed out the `list()` (refresh the page to see the updated comment).